# Unknown column 'AG' in 'where clause

Tags: php, mysql, identity-column

I'm getting this error the error(title) on such a simple query:

```
function getBranch($BranchID){
$query = "SELECT Branch FROM Branches WHERE BranchID = {$BranchID}";
$r = mysql_query($query);
if (!$r) echo "Failed Query: " . mysql_error();
  else return mysql_result($r, 0);
}
```

I know the mysql_ functions are being deprecated and I know the Column 'Branches' does exist. The var $BranchID is 'AG' when called and I've checked, that is a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. It's much better to use PDO and parameterized queries.

The specific problem with your query is that you are missing quotes around your string value:

```
$query = "SELECT Branch FROM Branches WHERE BranchID = '$BranchID'";
```

You should also ensure that you escape the value correctly with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
$query = "SELECT Branch FROM Branches WHERE BranchID = '" . 
          mysql_real_escape_string($BranchID) . "'";
```

**Related**

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks it worked! Don't normally make that mistake. Need coffee lol